# Selecting buttons by default extjs4.1

Tags: javascript, dom, button, extjs, extjs4.1

I have two groups of button (in Extjs 4.1) which can be checked only one at time. The problem is that i want one of them to be checked at the beginning (when the grid loads). The code is below:

```
{
    xtype : 'checkboxgroup',
    store : checked,
    columns : 3,
    vertical : false,
    singleSelect: true,
    items : [
        {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'name',
        width: 75,
        toggleGroup: 'mygroup',
        enableToggle: true,
        listeners: {
                click: function(th) {
                //this == the button, as we are in the local scope
                    checked = [1,0,0];
                }}
        }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'buyer_member_id',
        width:100,
        toggleGroup: 'mygroup',
        enableToggle: true,
        listeners: {
                click: function(th) {
                //this == the button, as we are in the local scope
                    checked = [0,1,0];
                }}
        }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'id',
        width: 50,
        toggleGroup: 'mygroup',
        enableToggle: true,
        listeners: {
                    click: function(th) {
                //this == the button, as we are in the local scope
                    checked = [0,0,1];
                }}
        }
    ]}
```

I found some help [in the Sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?123704-Ext.select%28%29-selecting-buttons-by-class) but i couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the word:

```
    pressed: true,
```

To be inserted in the button configuration instructions.

Comment: And [this](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.button.Button) is the manual where i took it from.